# What does the Enlightenment desktop (E17) environment variable "PANTS=ON" do?

Tags: environment-variables, enlightenment

Installing the Enlightenment Window Manager (E17), results in an [environment variable being set](http://svn.enlightenment.org/svn/e/trunk/e/src/bin/e_main.c):

```
PANTS=ON
```

What does this environment variable do? What will happen if I set

```
PANTS=OFF
```

Comment: I advise trying this in private first. `PANTS=OFF` can have unfortunate consequences (e.g. may send unexpected [signals](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html)), and may abruptly terminate connections, even between close peers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I'm not an active Enlightement developer, I am taking an educated guess.

On the Enlightenment developer mailing list, there are a lot of [references](http://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=enlightenment-users@lists.sourceforge.net&q=pants%20on&submit.x=0&submit.y=0), usually in closing, to various states of pants. These appear to be tongue in cheek references meant for humor. It seems to have been started, or at least perpetuated, by lead developer [The Rasterman](http://www.rasterman.com/).

```
pants on! (or skirts... whatever tickles your fancy).
:)

-- 
------------- Codito, ergo sum - "I code, therefore I am" --------------
The Rasterman (Carsten Haitzler)    ras...@rasterman.com
```

It's probably safe to assume that the environment variable is a nod to this inside developer joke.

Of course the easiest is to set `PANTS=OFF` and see if it has any obvious effect. If you are very curious, subscribe to the [Enlightenment developer list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/enlightenment-users) and ask there.

Comment: Indeed, grepping the source code, `e_util_env_set("PANTS", "ON");` is the only place `PANTS` occurs. So, yeah, it probably does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Since I worked with Raster back in the late 90's I can tell you what this is about.
This is a faint memory, so take this a "close enough" and not absolute truth:

One day he was working from home, but had a webcam running which I guess he kind of forgot about (probably low quality for back then), and some coworkers noticed he was working in his boxer shorts, for which everyone got a good laugh.

In e16, Michael Jennings made an epplet called E-pants which you could click on and would toggle between pants on and pants off, as a tongue in cheek reminder. The epplet did otherwise nothing useful whatsoever

While that epplet is gone in E17, the variable PANTS is likely yet another reminder of that incident, and can otherwise easily be ignored.